# How to restart Kubernetes deployment with persistent volume claims?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a deployment (starterservice) that deploys a single pod with a persistent volume claim. This works. However restart fails:

```
kubectl rollout restart deploy starterservice
```

The new pod is started before the old one has terminated and it cannot attach the volume (Multi-Attach error for volume "pvc-..."). I can work around this by scaling to zero and then back up to 1 instead:

```
kubectl scale --replicas=0 deployment/starterservice
kubectl scale --replicas=1 deployment/starterservice
```

I was wondering if there was a way to get `kubectl rollout restart` to wait for the old pod to terminate before starting a new one? Tx.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set deployment strategy = recreate.

```
spec:
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
```

The difference between the `Recreate` strategy compared to `RollingUpdate` (default) is that `Recreate` will terminate the old pod before creating new one while `RollingUpdate` will create new pod before terminating the old one.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#recreate-deployment